# Facing bootstrap rendering issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, rendering

I am trying to use Bootstrap but it seems like the rendering turns wrong. My buttons don't really look like as expected.

[image]

I am developing with Adobe Brackets if this matters. Also, I am only concerned with Chrome.

Any ideas what could happen here ? Of course I did'nt tweak the bootstrap css's on my side.

Comment: Check if the bootstrap.min.css has the normalize.css included. (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-normalize) .You can further check by including manually a reset css or the normalize css before the bootstrap.min.css include.

Comment: I added normalize.css as suggested but it only produced small effects and not a full reset. Thanks anyway.

Comment: can you show us your code or a fiddle?

Comment: Hi sorry for late feedback. I finally chose another css frameworkwhich works fine enough to me. Thanks for your concerns and efforts.